# How to compare two vectors with different dimensions to get logical array?

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors with different dimensions. To make it simple,lets say

```
A = rand(30, 1);
B = rand(10, 2);
```

Basically, I want this: if `A(i,1)<=B(i,1) & A(i,1)>=B(i,2)` is true,then do sth. i tried to use for statement such as for i=size(A),obviously, theres problem because of the two dimensions. If anybody knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: What behaviour do you want when i = 25 for example seeing as B(25,1) is not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
%# find out which array is longer
lenA = size(A,1);
lenB = size(B,1);

minLength = min(lenA,lenB);

%# do vectorized comparison
trueOrFales = all(A(1:minLength)<=B(1:minLength,1)) && ...
    all(A(1:minLength)>=B(1:minLength,2))
```

Comment: hi Jonas,thanls for your help. Again, my A is larger than B. I have no problem if the size of A is maller than the size of B.

Comment: @Lei: If you know that A is always larger than B, you can just write `minLength = size(B,1);`. Anyway, if you found this answer helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this

```
for i = min(size(A), size(B))
   if  A(i,1)<=B(i,1) & A(i,1)>=B(i,2)
```

then do stuff.

Not really familiar with Matlab, and to lazy to start it; hope it helps.

Comment: Hi George,Thanks for your help. But this only works if the size of A is smaller than the size of B. In my case, size of A is larger than B

Comment: Sorry, but isn't `min(A, B)` supposed to return the smaller number between the two of them? Also, I've forgotten to close bracket for min. Of course, you can only compare for the number of elements of the smaller array... for the rest you need a new for to continue do the stuff

Comment: Hi George,I know that. Thanks again for your help. The thing is that I wanna compare larger size of A to the smaller size of B! I dont know if there's any way could do this.

Comment: for i = min(size(A), size(B)): This will only run twice, once where i is the smallest number of rows (in this case 10) and once where i is the smallest number of columns (1)... Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: Hi Dan, I think it will run 10 times since i=min(size(A),size(B)) is from 1 to 10. Let me clarify my problem again. What I want is compare each row of A with each row of B. For my data, each row of A should follow in the range of B(i,:). I dont know which which row of B, thats why I need a code to do so. But, each row of A only follow in one row of B! So i was wondering what i can do for this problem. Of course, size(A)>> size(B)